# How can i create single tree structure using Gojs

Tags: javascript, gojs

I have a set of data from my database.

```
var nodeDataArray = [
    {key: 45, name:"101",email:"101",pic: ""},
    {key: 49, parent: 46,name:"102-1",email:"102-1",pic: ""},
    {key: 47, parent: 46,name:"102-2",email:"102-2",pic: ""},
    {key: 46, parent: 43,name:"102",email:"102",pic: ""},
    {key: 48, parent: 46,name:"102-3",email:"102-3",pic: ""},
    
    
    {key: 54, parent: 45,name:"101-1",email:"101-1",pic: ""},
    {key: 53, parent: 45,name:"101-2",email:"101-2",pic: ""},
    {key: 52, parent: 45,name:"101-3",email:"101-3",pic: ""},
    ];
```

What i want to is only single tree parent name 101, But it display 2 tree structure.

[Screenshot output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icJIy.png)

Hopefully someone can help me.

Comment: `key: 46` node specifies `parent: 43`, while `key: 43` node doesn't exist. Did you want to write `parent: 45` there?

Comment: yes its not exit parent:43 on the dataArray provided.

This is the Senario:

new user display only his own node

also everytime new user add other new user 

automatically go to children of the new user.

The problem is if i fetch all data of my database and push to nodeDataArray i can see other tree structure

Comment: base on my screenshot attached i login to user 45 but i can see tree strcture of user 46.

i just want to see only tree structure of user 45

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the new Array that you assign to **Model.nodeDataArray** only contains data for the nodes that you want to show.

Perhaps you just need to start from an empty Array when you collect the new data for the new user.